# Can someone tell me what's wrong with the for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, char

So here's my code. What I wanted to do is to identify each of the unique letters in an array of Strings and save the unique letters in an character array. I tried the following code, but Eclipse is acting weirdly. It will only add the first letter in the array of strings and it will add the same letter repeated to the char array, which isn't what I intend to do nor does the code look like it will achieve such things.

```
public class Minglish {   
 public static String answer(String[] words) {
    char[] letters = new char[25];
    int i = 0;
    //iterate through words to get every unique letters
    for (String word: words) {
        for (char letter: word.toCharArray()) {
            if (!(letters.toString().contains(String.valueOf(letter)))) {
                letters[i] = letter;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (letters.toString()); 
} 
}
```

Could someone explain to me if it's my code/logic's problem, or it's a bug from my compiler?

Also, when you try to print out the result array using

```
System.out.println
```

it will only print out the address of the String.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Take a look at what `letters.toString()` returns.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the problem. Note to myself - array.toString() returns the address of an array! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays dont override `toString` so you just get the `Object#toString` representation of the input array. You could do

```
return new String(letters);
```

Answer (score 0):

letters.toString() gives some wierd output. in java, either you have to override the toString method to see what do you want when you work with non pirimitive types or you have to create your own method to print them.

You can iterate them with a for loop to print, simple and quick solution :)

for the searching..

There can be many different implementations to do the search in an array but i use this one if data is small and not ordered.. Of course this kind of implementation can be used with other objects with the condution which is to use equals method instead of '=='. By the way, for generic Lists, java Collections class, provides sorting and searching methods

```
public int indexOf(char key, char[] arr) {
    // Like a linear search.. 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == key)
            return i;
    }
    return -1; //defeault return is -1
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is very helpful and detailed. But Reimeus answered first and he was right as well so I'll have to set him as the answer. I appreciate your help though! :)

Comment: Hi :) its not about getting any point or grades or etc.. My question has justbeen  answered by anohter guy and he tried to solve my problem even 3 times!. Can you believe that ? :) People like helping.. Nearly an hour ago, i was using this site for only asking smt but now i understand that i should help someone as long as i can.. The coomon point is this my frend :)

Comment: Very nice! Kudos to you :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the charValue() method and using that to map the characters onto the array directly. If you have all lowercase English characters, you can simply subtract the charValue() of the character 'a' from the charValue() of the lowercase character and get a number that will map perfectly onto an index of your array.

If you do this, you can actually keep count of the number of occurrences of any character(as an array of ints instead of chars), or use an array of bools.

Comment: Interesting approach... I'll give it a shot! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question... Like what @Reimeus' said, a

```
charArray.toString()
```

will only return the memory address of the array, instead of its string values. You can use

```
 new String(char[] array)
```

to get the string value of a character array, or

`String.valueOf(char[] array)`
could also work!